# Schedule multiple tasks in Spring

Tags: spring, scheduled-tasks

I have 2 Tasks which implements (my) PeriodicTask which implements Runnable. 
There is a code which works fine. But I expects plenty of Tasks in future and want to avoid registering each of them in TaskScheduler.
Is it possible TaskScheduler find all classes (which implement PeriodicTask) and schedule them.
There is also a problem how to set schedule params (let them be static final for beginning).

```
@Component
public class TaskScheduler {

    private final Task1 task1;
    private final Task2 test2;

    public TaskScheduler(Task1 task1, Task2 test2) {
        this.task1 = task1;
        this.test2 = test2;
    }
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 60 * 1000, initialDelay = 1000)
    public void scheduleTask1() {task1.run();}

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 3600 * 1000, initialDelay = 5 * 1000)
    public void scheduleTask2() {test2.run();}
}
```

Comment: did it help to solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement it without `@Scheduled` annotation:

```
@Component
public class TaskSchedulerComponent {

    @Autowired
    private ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler;


    public void schedulePeriodicTask(Runnable task, long delay, long period){

        PeriodicTrigger periodicTrigger
                = new PeriodicTrigger(period, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS);
        periodicTrigger.setFixedRate(true);
        periodicTrigger.setInitialDelay(delay);

        taskScheduler.schedule(task,periodicTrigger);
    }
}
```

Then in your `main` method you register all tasks, which should be executed periodically, with given delay and time period.

Note:
To make `@Scheduled` to use parameters, you can use values from property file like this:

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${fixed.delay}",initialDelay = ${init.delay})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is exactly what I need.